# Where to write predefined queries in django?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I am working with a team of engineers, and this is my first Django project.

Since I have done SQL before, I chose to write the predefined queries that the front-end developers are supposed to use to build this page (result set paging, simple find etc.).

I just learned Django QuerySet, and I am ready to use it, but I do not know on which file/class to write them.

Should I write them as methods inside each class in models.py? Django documentation simply writes them in the shell, and I haven't read it say where to put them.

Comment: Well, the idea of a framework like django is that you don't need to write your sql, but to use the QuerySet API instead. You mainly write the querysets in the views, wich handle the data to be displayed. If you want I can write an answer with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the Django pattern is that you will write your queries in your views in the `views.py` file.  Here you will take each of your predefined queries for a given URL and return a response that renders a template (that presumably your front end team will build with you.) or returns a JSON response (for example through Django Rest Framework for an SPA front-end).

The [tutorial is strong on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/), so that may be a better bet for where to put things than the docs itself.

Queries can be run anywhere, but django is built to receive Requests through the URL schema, and return a response.  This is typically done in the views.py, and each view is generally called by a line in the urls.py file.

If you're particularly interested in following the fat models approach and putting them there, then you might be interested in the `Manager` objects, which are [what define querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/) that you get through, for example `MyModel.objects.all()`

My example view (for a class based view, which provides information about a list of matches:

```
class MatchList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a Match.
    """
    queryset = Match.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MatchSerialiser
```

That queryset could be anything, though.

A function based view with a different queryset would be:

```
def event(request, event_slug):
    from .models import Event, Comment, Profile
    event = Event.objects.get(event_url=event_slug)
    future_events = Event.objects.filter(date__gt=event.date)
    comments = Comment.objects.select_related('user').filter(event=event)
    final_comments = []
    return render(request, 'core/event.html', {"event": event, "future_events": future_events})
```

edit:  That second example is quite old, and the query would be better refactored to: 
`future_events=Event.objects.filter(date__gt=event.date).select_related('comments')`

Edit edit:   It's worth pointing out, QuerySet isn't a language, in the way that you're using it.  It's django's API for the Object Relational Mapper that sits on top of the database, in the same way that [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) also does - in fact, you can swap out or use SQLAlchemy instead of using the Django ORM, [if you really wanted](https://engineering.betterworks.com/2015/09/03/sqlalchemy-and-django/).  Mostly you'll hear people talking about the Django ORM. :)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a preference with writing raw SQL vs ORM? Or does it depend on the project?

Comment: Almost exclusively ORM, in my experience.  I've mostly used raw SQL for connecting to external databases that don't have their tables controlled by the Django models.  I can only think of one or two cases where I've had to write raw SQL against my own Django models, and those were very esoteric, case specific instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some model `SomeModel` and you  wanted to access its `objects` via a raw SQL query you would do: `SomeModel.objects.raw(raw_query)`.

For example: `SomeModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_somemodel')`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries

Comment: And what of writing them in QuerySet?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to use SQL or Django's ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Django file structure:

```
app/
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py
    templates/
        app/
            my_template.html
```

In models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    #field definition and relations
```

In views.py:

```
from .models import MyModel

def my_view():
     my_model = MyModel.objects.all() #here you use the querysets
     return render('my_template.html', {'my_model': my_model}) #pass the object to the template
```

In the urls.py

```
from .views import my_view

url(r'^myurl/$', my_view, name='my_view'), # here you write the url that    points to your view
```

And finally in my_template.html

```
# display the data using django template
{% for obj in object_list %}
    <p>{{ obj }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```